# Creating Service Resource with Asset record type

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, field-service-lightning

We are trying to create *Service Resource* with *Asset* record type.

But getting the following error:

[image]

Found something [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fs_resource_fields.htm&type=5):

[image]

We tried giving Lightning Scheduler permission by follwoing [Manage Permissions for Lightning Scheduler](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=ls_manage_perms.htm&type=5).

We are not able to find Let a user be included in appointments in **Lightning Scheduler permission** in System permissions. What are we missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on same [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=ls_manage_perms.htm&type=5) to give Lightning Scheduler permission:

[image]

Comment: Hi @varun, I have a question-related to Asset. Does Resource Type = "Asset" only applicable for Lightning Scheduler? What is the significance of it in FSL? Thank you.

Comment: I was only adding as Asset type so not sure about others.